# Count number of products between dates, if condition matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, countif

I am doing an excel template to count the number of outstanding insurance claims by product group.

I have an excel table with 3 columns:

1. Product Group
2. First notification date (MM/DD/YYYY)
3. Status (OPEN, CLOSE, REOPEN)

The results table will have 5 columns:

1. Product Group
2. less than 1 Year
3. 1-3 Years
4. more than 3 Years

So basically I need to lookup each product group between certain dates where Status = OPEN or REOPEN.

I am not sure how to combine VLOOKUP and COUNTIF to achieve this.

Here is an image of the 2 tables:
[image: Tables Example]

Comment: You could look at countifs().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FILTER` if you have the newest version of Excel.

For example, where your data runs from A1:C100 and where your product group is in column F, try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISERROR(
FILTER($C$3:$C$100,
(($A$3:$A$100=$F3)*
(($C$3:$C$100="OPEN")+($C$3:$C$100="REOPEN"))*
(($B$3:$B$100<=DATEVALUE("7/31/2020"))*($B$3:$B$100>DATEVALUE("7/31/2018"))))))))
```

Note the `SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISERROR(` counts only the filtered columns that don't return an error, and that you can add another criteria to the date section with "*" as needed

[image]

If you don't have the newest version, `COUNTIFS` could help. But be careful, `COUNTIFS` only supports "and" logic, so you will not be able to directly check if your criteria is either "OPEN" or "REOPEN". As a workaround for this specific case, we can test whether the criteria is not "CLOSE". For example:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$100, $F3,
$C$3:$C$100, "<>"&"CLOSE",
$B$3:$B$100, "<="&DATEVALUE("7/31/2020"),
$B$3:$B$100, ">"&DATEVALUE("7/31/2018"))
```

Comment: So countif() only supports "and" logic, what about countifs() ?

Comment: Good catch, believe it is the same. Another option is to test against an array, so ```SUM(COUNTIFS(...$C$3:$C$100, {"OPEN", "CLOSE"},...)```